# The estimation deviation in specific angles of Circular array DOA in circular harmonic domain

Tags: doa

Recently, I study the MUSIC doa in the circular harmonic domain, but I found the estimation results always have a big bias in some specific angles(angles near to 0 or 180 degree), as showing in the  Figure[image], I'm so confused because the estimation deviation in other angles is small, can someone told me the possible reason?

Comment: Do you find these results consistent for all data sets?

Comment: Yes, I set different T60/SNR（This figure‘s setting isT60=200ms, SNR=15dB), and the tendency is similar(the bias of estimation of the sources near to 0 or 180 degrees is large).Ps: the size of circles define the RMSE of estimation(which is amplified by a constant factor to show clearly)

Comment: What estimation algo have you deployed? That could let us know further on why we see this behavior

Comment: I used Circular Harmonic domain MUCIC（Transfer element domain data into circular harmonic domain and then applying broadband CSS MUSIC)